# Will running node.js with Apache causes too much performance degradation?

Tags: apache, node.js, proxy

I am trying to run Apache and node.js on the same Amazon EC2 instance. After research online, I came up with the following solution:

1. run Apache on port 9000
2. run node.js apps on port 8001, 8002 and so on.
3. create a [reverse proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) in node.js, running on port 80. It routes requests to different ports based on the hostname.

This solution works. (Although I haven't found a way to start node.js automatically)
My question is, will running multiple node instance causes performance degradation? Or will the reverse proxy be a problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I've written a little guide based on this information and others, with example files: http://gun.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-node-js-server-with-example/ Maybe this will help you

Comment: Hi Xi, will it be possible for you to share your Apache configuration to handle multiple Node.js servers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Performance Degradation

On the contrary. If all you do with node is proxying, the overload is insignificant (as compared to apache's). I do have a quite similar setup as yours (small virtual machine, 3 legacy apache websites, node.js proxying and enhancement). So far, apache is the resource eater, not my node apps, which nonetheless proxy/filter/intercept every incoming http request

Here's my setup :

### main proxy

which handles all incoming requests (for as many domains as you like) : I personally use [nodejitsu's http-proxy](http://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which is very robust and simple to configure

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var options = {

  hostnameOnly: true,
  router: {    
    'domain1.com': '127.0.0.1:8081',
    'www.domain1.com': '127.0.0.1:8081',
    'subdomain1.domain1.com': '127.0.0.1:8082',
(...)
    'domain2.com': '127.0.0.1:8090',
(...)

   }
}

var mainProxy = httpProxy.createServer(options);
mainProxy.listen(8080);
```

You can redirect to apache directly from the option object, or do some more url parsing in another (middleware) node app on a different port.

**WARN**: if you don't wish to install/run node as 'root' (which I'd strongly advise in a production environement) : redirect port 80 to some other port with an IPTABLE directive (let's say 8080) where this proxy runs (see here for [detailed example of Iptable directives](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80)). Mine, on a debian squeeze, reads :

```
#REDIRECT port 80 to 8080
$IPTABLES -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

### node apps

which do some URL parsing with regexes, or whatever you need. Ex: redirect to a few (legacy) apache servers which (in my case) only serve legacy content not yet served by the 'in developement' node apps.

## Daemonisation

There are several solutions to make node run as a daemon. My favorite two are :

- [nodemon](http://github.com/remy/nodemon) will monitor all files in your node app folder and subfolder for change and restart the node app on file change. It's perfect for a development environment
- [forever](http://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) (yet again by Nodejitsu) will restart your node app if ever it stops. It's very customisable.

Also :

- [init.d script](https://gist.github.com/715255) : I've written this debian init.d script for my own servers (should work on ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Node is really really fast and it's build for handling thousands of connections in the same time, so using a proxy built with it won't be a problem at all in my opinion.